# how to run a java/bin command using java?

Tags: java

**Hi,
     How to run java/ jdk or jre /bin command using java program???**

Comment: Next time, give people examples of methods you already have attempted. It would appear more that you actually put in some efforts before you asked the question.

Comment: Can you rephrase this or provide more information?  This isn't very clear...

Comment: i got answer below it is working fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`javax.tools.JavaCompiler`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) and possibly [`Runtime.exec(String command)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 3):

Try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.

Some useful links:

- http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html
- http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html